# Javascript: Get SharePoint Web Part - Objects to display on page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am a young software engineer working on a mobile view for SharePoint 2013. For this, I have to access `SharePoint Web Part - Objects with javascript`.

The javascript should be linked in the Masterpage and starts after the page is done loading. Then, it should modify web parts.

For example, I want to resize web parts to fit to the max. available screen-resolution.

I want to turn the standard navigation into a drop down. 
I want to fetch single informations out of different web parts and work with it.
I want to do change basically everything you can see on a standard page. :D If I am on the false road, pls tell me so.
I do not want anybody to post a link to a script or smth. - I wanna do the work ;)

But if you could give me a good hint or anything like that, I would highly appreciate it.

I already did a lot of research but due to the complex documentation of Microsoft's Products I did not find a proper solution. I think it's kind of a sad thing to be like that, because SharePoint is a great tool you could do so much with, if there would only be a document telling you how and where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of doing a different master page and layouts for mobile devices and have a redirection on the server side that when it detects the user agent of a mobile device that you're interested on redirecting it points the user to the mobile site? You wouldn't need to do the whole thing with JavaScript/jQuery since you could have the master and the layouts have the size that you want from the start. You could limit the width of the web part zones with some custom css as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi bostero2,
thank you for answering.
Yes, your approach seems to be the way to go for this.
The problem is that I need this knowledge for other projects as well, besides using it in mobile related thematics.
And I thought, if I would get used to work with that method, I could basically do everything I want in SharePoint ;)